# can sodium persulfate etch or damage a titanium heater?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, redox

I use Sodium Persulfate to etch copper on a PCB process. I have been using glass heater on the etching tank but the glass is too fragile; it breaks too easily.

I read that titanium heater is used commercially (in aquariums as well). I don't know much about chemistry, could anyone tell me if it is okay to use titanium with Sodium Persulfate?

Sodium Persulfate to water ratio is 1:10 and the maximum temperature is about 50 C.

Comment: what do you mean by 5dm2? Five liters of water (liter = dm$^3$)?

Comment: I copied pasted from the description on https://www.elfa.se/elfa3~se_en/elfa/init.do?item=49-577-26&toc=0&q=etching+powder   I keep acid/water ratio 1:10

Comment: So what it says there is that 140g of powder is enough to etch 6 dm$^2$ (about 100 square inches).  So 6dm2 is not part of the formula; can you edit your question accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the surface of the immersed element is all titanium, the answer appears to be that it won't get corroded unless the temperature is much higher than 50$^\circ$C; see http://www.azom.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=1336

The case is changed if there are joints or parts made of something else, as in this illustration: http://www.saltwatereddies.com/content-popup_image/pID-2199/popup_image.html

I would think that would not be so safe.

Of course, if you've been breaking glass heating elements right and left, you have little to lose by trying the titanium one...